# Processing weighted data for curve fitting in R

Tags: r, curve-fitting

Hi…I have a very basic question regarding the input of weighted data into R. Currently I have to process data (mostly for curve fitting purposes) similar to the following:

```
    > head(mydata, 10)
       v        sf
    1  0.3003434  3.933106
    2  0.3027852  5.947432
    3  0.3052270  9.832596
    4  0.3076688 12.927439
    5  0.3101106 14.197519
    6  0.3125525 13.572904
    7  0.3149943 11.691078
    8  0.3174361  9.543095
    9  0.3198779  8.048558
    10 0.3223197  7.660252
```

The first column is the data (increasing & equidistant), while the 2nd column gives the frequency (weights), currently these weights don't add up to one, but I can easily fix that.

Now, I searched for weighted data in R and the closest I found was via using the survey package and the svydesign() command, but is it really that hard?

What I did to work around my lack of knowledge, and that got me in trouble with the Kolmogorov_Smirnov test (more below), is the following:

```
    > y <- with(mydata, c(rep(v, times=floor(10*sf))))
```

which will repeat the elements of the first column in proportion to the corresponding weight (times 10 to get a whole number). But now the problem is, when I conduct the Kolmogorov-Smirnov goodness of fit test, I get a warning that the p-value can not be computed since the data has ties.

Question is: How can I input and process the data in its original form (i.e. as a frequency or probability table) for the purpose of curve fitting? Thanks.

Comment: You are basically making up a statistical approach as you go along without really describing the process  that resulted in these numbers. (KS distribution is not for discrete data which is what is producing the errors.) This is not necessarily a 'bad thing', but we might be able to give you better advice if you were more forthcoming about how this data was derived and what the intended interpretation might be. Why not work with original data and use `density` rather than fitting to a `histogram?`

Comment: The original data comes from an FFT analysis to wave data. The first column is frequency in hz, and the second column is the amplitude, which statistically can be viewed as the weight. What I would like to do is be able to use data in its original form and be able to conduct curve fitting tests with continuous distributions.

Comment: I'm puzzled. My understanding of a spectral composition of a periodic signal would not suggest that the frequency values could be "continuous".

Comment: The frequencies correspond to the modes of the Fourier transform of the wave. They are discrete, of course, but in a way, isn't any type of sample data discrete? The change in frequency is constant and it is about 0.002 hz. So, could you please elaborate on why you think the data has to be modeled discretely?